# Essenes' Beliefs in Comparison to Christianity

Tags: history, reference-request, judaism, sect

Does anyone know (with sources) what the Essenes taught and believed in relation to what Christ taught? Sources are much appreciated.

Comment: This is an area of much dispute.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essenes  for the range of views about Essenes.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other ancient Jewish sects, some think the Essenes were celibate (unmarried), that Jesus Himself may have been associated with them, and that the early Christians were defected Essenes. See [p. 18 fn 5 of Dyan 1993](https://archive.org/details/SpiritualMarriage/page/n34) for references.